# Generate a composite unique constraint/index with owned entity, in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an entity that owns another entity

```
public class Entity1
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public virtual int ID { get; set; }

  public string Property { get; set; }

  public Entity2 Description { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
   public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

and I need to create an index on Entity1.Property and Entity2.Test. The configuration is like this

```
builder.OwnsOne(pt => pt.Description);

builder.HasIndex(p => new { p.Property, p.Description.Test }).IsUnique();
//builder.HasIndex("Property", "Description_Test").IsUnique();
```

I tried both of the above code but they do not work. The first says

```
The properties expression 'p => new <>f__AnonymousType3`7(Property = p.DeviceClassId, 
Test = p.Description.Test)' is not valid. The expression should represent a property 
access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type:
't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.
Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression
```

and the second one says:

```
The property 'Description_test' cannot be added to the type 'Entity1' because there was no 
property type specified and there is no corresponding CLR property or field. To add a 
shadow state property the property type must be specified.
```

Can this be achieved without modifying the migration manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently EF Core doesn't support this feature yet.

See this issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11336

There is also a workaround offered, which I have not tested myself.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that solved for me, was deleting in the migration's directory the autogenerated file `DataContextModelSnapshot.cs` and running again the migration it was regenerated, had some databases already referenced in the migration file that was just deleting and was done...
Might not be the most elegant solution, but it does work.

---

Just for reference, it happened with the EF Core 6.0 twice.